# Installing Windows 7 onto Laptop in UEFI

Tags: windows-7, boot, bios, uefi, bcd

I want to install Windows 7 64-Bit onto my [laptop's](https://www.pcspecialist.co.uk/notebooks/optimusV-13/) SSD, in UEFI. I have written a Windows 7 ISO onto a USB memory stick, using Rufus. This seems to have worked without errors. But when I try to boot to it on the laptop I get an error saying:

> Windows failed to start.
>
> File: \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\BCD
>
> Info: an error occured trying to read the boot configuration data.

Im not exactly sure what this is saying but the "bcd" file is there and doesn't seem corrupted. I have tried this twice with different USB Drives. My Bios settings seem correct; I have disabled secure boot, SATA mode is AHCI. I have tried taking out the SSD and booting, but this doesn't work. I had Windows 7 working fine without UEFI before, but I decided to reinstall Windows for UEFI. The ISO is fine as I matched the checksums. Rufus has put the boot manager in the correct file as other sites suggest. I am using a USB 2.0 port as some sites suggest, but trying 3.0 gives the same error.

Although I would not mind that much going back to BIOS, I would like to find out how to fix this error.

Comment: BCD=Boot Configuration Data. Was the USB FAT32? Is the disk GPT not MBR? ALso see here http://forums.bit-tech.net/showthread.php?t=209045 and http://superuser.com/questions/676249/clean-install-of-windows-7-pro-64-bit-on-a-uefi-with-gpt-laptop

Comment: @RsyaStudios The disk is fat32 & GPT as Rufus does this for you. Thanks for the info on BCD and in the links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 7 doesn't support UEFI boot, you have to use it with legacy boot unless you want to upgrade to Windows 8