# Win7 x64 UEFI install error

Tags: windows-7, boot, partitioning, bios, uefi

I bought a Grundig 1452 b1n2 Laptop. It had Win8 x64 (2GB RAM, very slow) I decided to install Win7 x86 via USB (no DVD drive on the laptop).

After some struggle with the BIOS I managed to boot into linux mint live CD. I used GParted and deleted all partitions. (now, `unallocated-gpt`) Now I realized that BIOS is locked so I can't use legacy support. (boot type is: UEFI and isn't changeable) I prepared a USB for UEFI install but it returns with the error "Default Boot Device Missing or Boot Failed"

How can I install win7 or win8 x64 on this machine?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Turn secure boot back on and install win 8. Windows 7uefi does not have usb3 drivers and will not install on a USB device.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clean install of Windows 7 Pro 64-bit on a UEFI laptop with GPT partition?](http://superuser.com/questions/676249/clean-install-of-windows-7-pro-64-bit-on-a-uefi-laptop-with-gpt-partition) Also, see http://forums.bit-tech.net/showthread.php?t=209045, which more directly addresses the question.

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like an Instant Go device where the BIOS is **[device encrypted](https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?cid=475A0A48CA6D4035&resid=475a0a48ca6d4035%212512&wacqt=sharedby&app=WordPdf)**. Unfortunately we cannot verify that and decrypt the device since you wiped the disk.

I suggest you get Windows 8.1 back on the device because a) that is your only chance and b) Windows 7 would be slower than W 8.1 anyhow.