# how to install windows 7 with size more than 4 GB using gpt usb and UEFI mode?

Tags: windows-7, ntfs, uefi, gpt, fat32

I know that, in order to install Windows 7 on my windows 8.1 laptop, I must disable secure boot then use the diskpart command to convert my USB disk to GPT and format it as fat32.

I made every thing and succeeded...

When I tried to make this again, with a new copy of Windows 7 that is greater than 4 GB, I couldn't copy the files to my USB driver because fat32 does not support files larger than 4 GB.

What can I do to make my laptop accept NTFS file system to install this version of Windows ?

Comment: Windows 7 supports NTFS why would you use FAT32?  Windows 7 also being installed from a EFI disk, Windows 7 also supports GPT partition.  Why are you using FAT32?  Its not required to do what you want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clean install of Windows 7 Pro 64-bit on a UEFI laptop with GPT partition?](http://superuser.com/questions/676249/clean-install-of-windows-7-pro-64-bit-on-a-uefi-laptop-with-gpt-partition)

Comment: @Ramhound this is no dupe. You didn't understand the question. UEFI doesn't support NTFS, so you need to use FAT32 on USB thumb drives, but here the Install.wim must be <=4GB becasue of the FAT32 file size limitations.

Comment: @magicandre1981 All the Windows disk I own are EFI compatible, so your right, I didn't understand and that's the reason I asked.

Comment: Not even the whole Windows 7 SP1 ISO is 4GB, I don't see why install.wim shouldn't fit.

Answer (score 1):

The latest [Rufus Version](http://rufus.akeo.ie/) includes a free [NTFS driver for EFI](https://github.com/pbatard/uefi-ntfs) to use NTFS instead of FAt32 to avoid the 4GB file size limitation when creating a bootable USB thumb drive.

> - Version 2.0 (2015.03.03)
>
> Add seamless UEFI boot of NTFS partitions, for Windows ISOs with large files (>4GB)

Answer (score 0):

simply format your boot USB Stick with exFAT filesystem which can handle >4GB files fine and will be recognized by most UEFI (and BIOS). just tested it with a 6 year old Macbook

Comment: Macs are _in no way_ typical UEFI machines; their EFI implementation actually predates the UEFI specification and has some quirks not found in most UEFI PCs.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue with Windows 7 64 bit on some new laptops I was imaging. After the drivers and a few apps were installed, the install.wim file was almost 8GB! Obviously, that won't work on the the usual WinPE USB flash drive formatted with FAT32.
So, after making a duplicate copy of my Windows 7 install Flash Drive, I used the Windows 7 convert.exe to convert my bootable Windows 7 install FAT32 Flash drive to NTFS. Then I loaded my 8GB install.wim image onto the newly NTFS converted flash drive with ease. Next I booted this drive on my target machine and voila! Image installed without issue.
Hope that helps!
-Kev

Answer (score -2):

Few years ago I used **HP USB Disk Storage Format Tool** and **unetbootin** to do this. Check it out, should work.

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. At the very least you should provide more than just a link, for example some additional information about the software itself, for example how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Comment: ok im sorry, im going to read it