# Install Windows 7 on GPT partition

Tags: windows-7, boot, windows-10, partitioning, gpt

Today I got really frustrated when tried to upgrade a friend's Lenovo laptop from Win8 to Win10. The upgrade just fails no matter what I try... And I tried a lot of things...

Long story short, I decided to just clean-install Win7 on the partition of the Win8 installation. But then I discovered that the partition is GPT and Win7 cannot install there. I tried to make a bootable Win7 USB with Rufus setted for GPT partition installation but Rufus says that my ISO image of Win7 is not UEFI enabled (or w/e), and I can't find a way to create such an ISO.

So... I just want a clean straight-forward method of how to install Win7 on GPT partition (maybe create the proper ISO first? and then continue to make bootable USB with Rufus?). I know I can just complete format the drive (and all of it's 5-6 partitions) to get a clean one but the reason I don't, is so my friend will have the ability later on to use Lenovo's Recovery to go back to Win8.

Comment: Make sure you are using the 64bit version of Windows 7, it should give you the option to download x32 or x64 from Microsoft. Windows 7 64bit can boot via UEFI and install to a GPT disk. If it says it can't install to a GPT disk, you probably booted it in Legacy mode by accident. Many UEFI systems have a setting to enable Legacy-only, EUFI-only and Auto/Both. Make sure it is set to UEFI only. What error is rufus giving you exactly? You can read more here http://superuser.com/questions/676249/clean-install-of-windows-7-pro-64-bit-on-a-uefi-laptop-with-gpt-partition?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

I was unhappy with the performance of Windows 10 64 bit with my new motherboard and new CPU so I wanted to go back to windows 7 64 bit which I am happy with but since I installed new 240GB M.2 Hard Drive, I unplugged all other drivers, but when it come to "Install" I got the massage "You cannot install system because your hard drive is GPT partition style. After bit of reading what other people say, I returned to the BIOS and set first booting option to UEFI it installation went smooth as cake. Beautiful.