# Can't install Windows 7 on GPT partition

Tags: windows-7, boot, usb, partitioning, bios

I am at my wits end trying to figure out how to solve this problem for over ten hours now. I am trying to install Windows 7 on an old computer from a usb, and when I get to the partition selection screen, it will not allow me to install on any of them because the drive has the GPT partition style. I have made every concerted effort that I can do boot from my usb in UEFI mode, but it makes no difference at all, same error.  I have no intention of converting my drive to MBT. What can I do in this situation?

[Pic of drive, open 600gb partition is the target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVi6J.png)

I should also add that I tried to follow advice from Microsoft to remove the bootmgr file for whichever mode I did not want to use, in this case legacy BIOS, but this prevented the drive from booting normally, only showing me grub installed by woeusb. This seems to imply that no matter what I do the usb is booted in BIOS instead of UEFI.

Comment: "because the drive has the GPT partition style." - Windows 7 absolutely supports GPT.  So you have either NOT booted into UEFI mode or the ISO you are attempting to use does not support GPT.  You **CANNOT** installed Windows on a GPT partition if you boot into anything other than UEFI-only mode.

Comment: windows 7 is now unsupported, you really should be installing Windows 10. More info on UEFI install of 7. https://superuser.com/questions/676249/clean-install-of-windows-7-pro-64-bit-on-a-uefi-laptop-with-gpt-partition & https://askubuntu.com/questions/860729/is-it-possible-to-install-windows-7-alongside-ubuntu-and-windows-10-dualboot?noredirect=1#comment1327830_860729

Answer (score 0):

Try this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LSV7Bbsy1NE

Explains how to change GPT on fly while still installing.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1183094)